# Configuring pentaho's hdfs-vfs to pick up hdfs-site.xml

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, pentaho, apache-commons-vfs

I just started to use [Pentaho's](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-hdfs-vfs) HDFS [VFS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) and don't know much about this project.
I am trying to have my Hadoop config files read from an external location.  This seems to work fine for all files except [hdfs-site.xml](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-hdfs-vfs). The failure occurs in the VFS layer when trying to communicate with HDFS through the Pentaho HDFS VFS project. My gut tells me that pentaho is reading this file through some environment variable or other external pointer, but I can't seem to find it in their source.  Everything works fine when I manually place the hdfs-site.xml file in the compiled [war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28file_format%29) file but this will not suffice for me because I need to have this file in an external location so it can be changed by other processes.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before?  Could someone please let me know how to tell pentaho where to pick this file up from?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figure out a way to make pentaho hdfs works, all you need to do is adding hdfs-site.xml to your classpath. 
I did this when I start my jar file:

java -jar start.jar --lib=/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn1

And /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn1 is the directory where hdfs-site.xml reside.

Answer (score 0):

Will it be possible for you to provide more info? Are you talking about the VFS api distributed by pentaho ?